# API расписания на PHP

Tags: php, веб-программирование, api

Нужен совет по разработке типа API для сайта квестов.

У меня есть агрегатор квестов (PHP, Wordpress), на нем расписание сеансов квеструмов. Сейчас я с помощью Curl получаю со всех сайтов квеструмов следующие данные: квест, дата, время, свободен ли.

Хочу сделать API, так как с парсингом куча проблем.

Пока есть такой вариант, стыренный у одного из крупных агрегаторов:

1. Клиент у себя формирует json-файл с расписанием, откуда я получаю данные с помощью GET-запроса. Такой файл автоматически формируется каждый день и изменяется при бронировании сеанса (я бы вместо изменения файла добавила отправку post-запроса с данными бронирования на мой сайт).
2. Клиент формирует URL, на который я буду отправлять данные о бронировании уже с моего агрегатора post-запросом. Таким образом на моем сайте также можно будет забронировать сеанс, и владельцы квеструма получат эту бронь.

Надеюсь, понятно описала. Нормальный ли это алгоритм? Может, что-то не так, или можно что-нибудь улучшить или сделать по-другому? Буду благодарна за совет.

Comment: то есть хотите свои проблемы перевесить на клиентов? они рады не  будут, и врядли будут эту вашу проблему решать. и второе - раз в день формирование это редко. обновления должны быть постоянными по факту заказа, иначе какой смысл?

Comment: Клиенты в этом как раз и заинтересованы. Вообще, это нормальная практика для квеструмов. большинство сами смогут интегрировать. Про формирование раз в день - согласна, потому и добавила: "(я бы вместо изменения файла добавила отправку post-запроса с данными бронирования на мой сайт)"

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, тот агрегатор, чью документацию я взяла, отправляет гет-запрос раз в 10 минут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В теории все замечательно расписано, только это мало применимо к практике. 99% владельцев сайтов квестов не будут на это заморачиваться. Тем более, если им требуется ежедневно выдавать расписание в JSON и получать через POST-запросы данные о бронировании (у нас большинство интернет-магазинов даже нормальный YML-файл для Яндекс.Маркета не делает, что уже говорить о квестах).

Используйте лучше прямой парсинг с сайтов квестов. А при бронировании у вас отправляйте уведомление на email владельца квеста. Это наиболее надежный способ, котрый позволит охватить максимальную бизнес-аудиторию.

> Хочу сделать API, так как с парсингом куча проблем.

Легче сделать один нормальный парсер, чем пересадить значимый процент владельцев квестов на API. Если же хотите брать подготовленные данные - порекомендуйте владельцам квестов держать у себя на сайте простой текстовый файл (по типу robots.txt), где будет в простой форме расписание. Его можно будет обновлять как вручную, так и через скрипты. Это намного проще, чем тот же JSON и в минимальном виде даже не требует навыков программирования. Отправку данных по бронированию лучше сделайте по email. Все равно этот канал является основным для большинства владельцев квестов.

Comment: Сейчас так и делаю. Но пару месяцев назад половина сайтов автоматически заблокировала мой скрипт. Владельцы утверждают, что они этого не делали. На данный момент для этих сайтов используется статическое расписание, где не показаны забронированные сеансы.

Comment: Об этой проблеме писала уже здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234931/curl-cant-get-html

Comment: @www см. абзац про текстовый файл в моем ответе (только дописал).

Comment: Ага, увидела. Спасибо!

Comment: @www еще немного дополнил ответ. попробуйте провести эксперимент с для начала с этим файлом. если народ втянется - вы всегда его можете переключить на полноценное API.

Comment: @www по вашему вопросу с curl - там 502 ошибка. вполне возможно, что сервер просто на какое-то время сдох. в данном конкретном случае надо смотреть открывалась ли страница в это время в браузере, а также как сервер будет реагировать, если ему слать запросы с разными cookies, user-agent и api. на будущее, если выполняете регулярных парсинг с внешних ресурсов - заведите некоторое количество прокси, будет проще жить)

Comment: Ну, в принципе, да. Посмотрим, как они отреагируют. Дело в том, что часть из них уже подключены к каким-то агрегаторам. Так что тема будет им знакома.